# How to generate & prefix Identity column (from an existing table) when renaming a document using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am renaming multiple pdf documents. Part of the renaming process is that any new document being renamed has to start from the last identity value that is in an existing SQL table. For instance, last identity value is 3425 and doc name is MyDocument thus I want the renamed doc to look like: 3426_MyDocument.pdf.  Does anyone have any idea how I can go about implementing this in SSIS? I can use the File System Task to rename the document but I am not really sure how I can create a variable that would start from the last identity value in the table.
I am thinking of using a proc that verifies the last identity value and adds 1, which I am not sure if it will work: 
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table') + ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))

Sample of current table:

```
ID     FILENAME 
332442 332442_Statement.pdf
```

I already have a package that traverses into folders/subfolders and copy files to the network. 2) I have an Execute SQL that inserts into a temp table that holds the identity values and folder names. The identity value of the temp table and the actual table will have the same last identity value. I have a Foreach Loop Container and inside it I have a File System Task to rename the docs. I am not sure how I can create a variable to assign the identity value from the temp table so that I can prefix it when I rename the docs

Comment: Is there any correlation between rows in the table and PDF documents? i.e. when you get to the tenth document in, that would be renamed 3436_MyDocument.PDF, but is that ever written back to the table?

Comment: Yes, there is a correlation and it will be written to the table. Among others, the table has identity column and docName which is prefixed by the identity value. I am trying to find a simple/short way to rename the documents by prefixing the identity value and the identity value in the table and the prefixed value must be the same. I have an execute sql task that will import all the directory and will parse it later based on the specification of the columns. Hope it makes sens.

Comment: This is not obvious from the question. Anyway. Create a package, add a package variable to hold the record number. Drop on a for each file loop and set it up to pick up all the files in your folder. Do that first. Here is an example of setting up the for each file loop: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-the-foreach-loop-container/

Comment: Your `ROW_NUMBER` solution is OK but if something gets inserted into th table in the meantime your numbers will all be wrong. Better to use a for each file loop to insert/update records one by one

Comment: With regards to the identity, you should not find the last and add one because in the meantime another process could grab the same number. Instead you should _reserve_ the number by actually inserting a record into the table then using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to pick the identity you just generated. Then after you rename the file, update your previously inserted record with the new correct file name.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @Nick, let me try to simplify the question: I have a table like this                                                                                                   **ID**               **FILENAME**
**332442**      **332442_Statement.pdf**
And I want the next doc name in the folder to start with **332443_MyDoc.pdf**. I only want to find a solution to rename the docs by populating the identity value from the table. Makes sense? may be not :-(

Comment: Do any of my prior comments make sense to you? Have you tried any of the steps I suggested? Do you understand what I'm getting at? Could there be many documents in the folder when the package is run? How do the documents arrive in the folder? Does someone save them there? Will that person be running the package somehow or will the package be running overnight? Is this table inside SQL Server? The question might be simple but the real life situation is always far more complicated than you think. I have edited the question to include your information.

Comment: I could give you a simple answer that matches your requirement but there are many cases where it will fail, be buggy or give incorrect results, all do to other factors which you have not explained. In addition I won't spend time explaining answers if it's clear the poster doesn't read or doesn't understand the comments. Is it necessary to use SSIS or is it OK to use some other tool like VBScript or Powershell?. These other tools require a lot less 'plumbing' to work.

Comment: Yes, what you say makes absolutely sense. Yes, I am trying your suggestions. PowerShell-they don’t allow it, and VBScript-I’m not a developer and won’t understand what I should do with it.  The package will run manually till the files are renamed and copied over to the network. The documents are in folders and subfolders and they are manually placed in these folders. The goal is to copy the docs to a network drive and rename them before/after they’re copied over to the network (like IdentValue_DocName.pdf). The doc names & identity values will be inserted into actual SQL Server table at last.

Comment: 1) I already have a package that traverses into folders/subfolders and copy files to the network. 2) I have an Execute SQL that inserts into a temp table that holds the identity values and folder names. The identity value of the temp table and the actual table will have the same last identity value. I have a Foreach Loop Container and inside it I have a File System Task to rename the docs. I am not sure how I can create a variable to assign the identity value from the temp table so that I can prefix it when I rename the docs. Sorry for all the confusion and unclear post.

Comment: That's great you clearly have made some effort here. Here is an example of how you use the contents of a table to drive a loop, using a _for each ADO_ task: http://pldineshtech.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/loop-through-each-row-in-table-using.html. So I suggest you: 1. Populate the table from the _current_ filenames, generating the identity as you go. 2. Now loop through this table using a for each ado loop, renaming the files. I think you should do this with one table with a status column rather than using two tables or temp tables. If that interests you I'll write this up in an answer

Comment: @Nic I am on the process of finishing it except when files are renamed, the it assigns the same identity value to all the files. But once I do complete it, I will keep you posted.

Comment: Is it worth me posting a detailed answer?

Comment: @Nick - thank you so VERY much for your help. Here is the for the answer I got : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fe80caea-cd23-4759-8456-e29d487eb4a6/add-identity-value-before-doc-name?forum=sqlintegrationservices&prof=required

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but two things: Firstly, that solution is not watertight. Like I already said if two processes are running this they'll get the same number, so the solution can not scale. You'll find many explanations online of why `MAX(identityvalue)` is a bad idea. Secondly... its kind of impolite to cross post the same question to many sites.

Comment: I replaced the identity max(identvalue) with (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.table')+ IDENT_INCR('dbo.table')). The table won't be modified by anyone and one person only updates it. I want to extend my gratitude for your help and apologies for cross posting... I was not aware of it and I am learning my lessons now. Sorry again.

Comment: Just be aware that your solution has a possible future concurrency bug. It's a 'bad' pattern, but there's only one way to learn! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

> I am not really sure how I can create a variable that would start
>   from the last identity value in the table.

Create a package variable and populate it with an `EXECUTE SQL` task that Selects the MAX() of the Identity column + 1.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below query to create prefix identity column

```
CREATE table SerilaPrefix(
id int identity(1,1) ,
Prefix_id as cast('Prefix_'+ RIGHT('0000'+cast(id AS varchar),4) as varchar),
Name varchar(max));

INSERT INTO SerilaPrefix(Name ) VALUES ('Test String');
```